# Alternative to u'' for unicode strings

Tags: python

I have the following asp script which uses python 2.5:

```
<%@ Language = Python  CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="sv" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        Jellö Wörld<br>
<%
Response.Write(u'Hellö Wörld<br>') 
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works correctly, hurrah! However, it will become annoying if I have to use u'' all over the place. What alternatives are there? Is there any future I can import so that I can have python3 like strings?

Thanks for your help,

Barry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

However, you will need 2.6 or later for this to work.

Comment: I'm stuck with 2.5 just now... any other options?

Comment: Nothing that would be more elegant than using `u''`, as far as I know.

Comment: To elaborate on Thomas K's comment - probably something horrible like monkey-patching the `str` class to be the `unicode` class instead. Don't go there.